# How to solve MSDTC Does not work error when communicate between two Servers?

Tags: iis, msdtc

My MVC application runs in IIS installed in a server. The sql server database is host in another server. The IP of the server that contains the database included in the connection string.

The MSDTC service of both servers are enabled an in running state, but when saving a record (which executes through a transaction scope) it gives an exception with a message -

"Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been disabled. Please enable DTC for network access in the security configuration for MSDTC using the Component Services Administrative tool."

Answer (score 1):

First check if MSDTC is running:

Execute: services.msc > Distributed Transaction Coordinator (right click) > Start.

That should make the MSDTC start running.
Now, in some cases, the inbound/outbound configuration of MSDTC blocks communication. Then, both in application server and SQL server, you should do:

Execute: dcomcnfg.exe > Console root > Component services > Computers > My Computer > Distributed Transaction Coordinator > Right click on Local DTC > Properties

On the open screen, select security tab, then check 'Network DTC Access', 'Allow inbound' and 'Allow Outbound' boxes with the No Authentication Required Radio.

This will enable MSDTC communication with external agents.